# "Missing URL" error on initializing jollyday.HolidayManager in Stanford NLP library

Tags: java, clojure, stanford-nlp

Starting up a Java app that uses the Stanford NLP library, I get an error that suggests that JollyDayHolidays.java is being initialized incorrectly. You can see the error here:

http://javadox.com/de.jollyday/jollyday/0.4.7/de/jollyday/HolidayManager.java.html

```
public static final HolidayManager getInstance(final URL url, Properties properties) {
    if (url == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Missing URL.");
    }
    HolidayManager m = isManagerCachingEnabled() ? getFromCache(url.toString()) : null;
    if (m == null) {
        m = createManager(url, properties);
    }
    return m;
}
```

I am getting the "Missing URL" error.

However, I don't call this code. I never get near it. Rather, this is called deep inside of the Stanford NLP library. So how can I influence how this is initialized?

My own app is a Clojure wrapper around a Java app. I can see the lexers loading, and then the error:

```
Adding annotator ner

Initializing JollyDayHoliday for SUTime from classpath: edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/jollyday/Holidays_sutime.xml as sutime.binder.1.

Exception:

edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading$ReflectionLoadingException: 
Error creating edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl 
{:cause 
{:cause 
{:cause 
{:cause 
{:class java.lang.NullPointerException, :message "Missing URL.", :trace-elems (
{:method "getInstance", :class "de.jollyday.HolidayManager", :java true, :file "HolidayManager.java", :line 190} 
{:method "init", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays", :java true, :file "JollyDayHolidays.java", :line 52} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.Options", :java true, :file "Options.java", :line 90} 
{:method "init", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java", :line 45} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java", :line 39} 
{:method "newInstance0", :class "sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line nil} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line 62} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line 45} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "java.lang.reflect.Constructor", :java true, :file "Constructor.java", :line 422} 
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassFactory", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 229} 
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 378} 
{:method "loadByReflection", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading", :java true, :file "ReflectionLoading.java", :line 38} 
{:method "create", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java", :line 57} 
{:method "createExtractor", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java", :line 38} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier", :java true, :file "NumberSequenceClassifier.java", :line 79} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner", :java true, :file "NERClassifierCombiner.java", :line 68} 
{:method "ner", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations", :java true, :file "AnnotatorImplementations.java", :line 99} 
{:method "create", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$6", :java true, :file "AnnotatorFactories.java", :line 319} 
{:method "get", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool", :java true, :file "AnnotatorPool.java", :line 85} 
{:method "construct", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 289} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 126} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 122} 
{:method "start", :class "com.garlicapp.nlp.Initialize", :java true, :file "Initialize.java", :line 35} 
{:method "invoke0", :class "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line nil} 
{:method "invoke", :class "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line 62} 
{:method "invoke", :class "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line 43} 
{:method "invoke", :class "java.lang.reflect.Method", :java true, :file "Method.java", :line 497} 
{:method "invokeMatchingMethod", :class "clojure.lang.Reflector", :java true, :file "Reflector.java", :line 93} 
{:method "invokeNoArgInstanceMember", :class "clojure.lang.Reflector", :java true, :file "Reflector.java", :line 313} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.query", :clojure true, :file "query.clj", :line 19} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start-query", :ns "dandelions.start", :clojure true, :file "start.clj", :line 37} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.start", :clojure true, :file "start.clj", :line 59} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.core", :clojure true, :file "core.clj", :line 10} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "-main", :ns "dandelions.core", :clojure true, :file "core.clj", :line 24} 
{:method "invoke", :class "clojure.lang.RestFn", :java true, :file "RestFn.java", :line 397} 
{:method "applyToHelper", :class "clojure.lang.AFn", :java true, :file "AFn.java", :line 152} 
{:method "applyTo", :class "clojure.lang.RestFn", :java true, :file "RestFn.java", :line 132} 
{:method "main", :class "dandelions.core", :java true, :file nil, :line nil}), :trimmed-elems (
{:method "getInstance", :class "de.jollyday.HolidayManager", :java true, :file "HolidayManager.java", :line 190} 
{:method "init", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays", :java true, :file "JollyDayHolidays.java", :line 52} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.Options", :java true, :file "Options.java", :line 90})}, :class java.lang.RuntimeException, :message "Error initializing binder 1", :trace-elems (
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.Options", :java true, :file "Options.java", :line 92} 
{:method "init", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java", :line 45} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java", :line 39} 
{:method "newInstance0", :class "sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line nil} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line 62} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line 45} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "java.lang.reflect.Constructor", :java true, :file "Constructor.java", :line 422} 
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassFactory", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 229} 
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 378} 
{:method "loadByReflection", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading", :java true, :file "ReflectionLoading.java", :line 38} 
{:method "create", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java", :line 57} 
{:method "createExtractor", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java", :line 38} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier", :java true, :file "NumberSequenceClassifier.java", :line 79} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner", :java true, :file "NERClassifierCombiner.java", :line 68} 
{:method "ner", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations", :java true, :file "AnnotatorImplementations.java", :line 99} 
{:method "create", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$6", :java true, :file "AnnotatorFactories.java", :line 319} 
{:method "get", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool", :java true, :file "AnnotatorPool.java", :line 85} 
{:method "construct", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 289} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 126} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 122} 
{:method "start", :class "com.garlicapp.nlp.Initialize", :java true, :file "Initialize.java", :line 35} 
{:method "invoke0", :class "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line nil} 
{:method "invoke", :class "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line 62} 
{:method "invoke", :class "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line 43} 
{:method "invoke", :class "java.lang.reflect.Method", :java true, :file "Method.java", :line 497} 
{:method "invokeMatchingMethod", :class "clojure.lang.Reflector", :java true, :file "Reflector.java", :line 93} 
{:method "invokeNoArgInstanceMember", :class "clojure.lang.Reflector", :java true, :file "Reflector.java", :line 313} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.query", :clojure true, :file "query.clj", :line 19} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start-query", :ns "dandelions.start", :clojure true, :file "start.clj", :line 37} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.start", :clojure true, :file "start.clj", :line 59} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.core", :clojure true, :file "core.clj", :line 10} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "-main", :ns "dandelions.core", :clojure true, :file "core.clj", :line 24} 
{:method "invoke", :class "clojure.lang.RestFn", :java true, :file "RestFn.java", :line 397} 
{:method "applyToHelper", :class "clojure.lang.AFn", :java true, :file "AFn.java", :line 152} 
{:method "applyTo", :class "clojure.lang.RestFn", :java true, :file "RestFn.java", :line 132} 
{:method "main", :class "dandelions.core", :java true, :file nil, :line nil}), :trimmed-elems (
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.Options", :java true, :file "Options.java", :line 92} 
{:method "init", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java", :line 45} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java", :line 39})}, :class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, :message nil, :trace-elems (
{:method "newInstance0", :class "sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line nil} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line 62} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line 45} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "java.lang.reflect.Constructor", :java true, :file "Constructor.java", :line 422} 
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassFactory", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 229} 
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 378} 
{:method "loadByReflection", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading", :java true, :file "ReflectionLoading.java", :line 38} 
{:method "create", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java", :line 57} 
{:method "createExtractor", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java", :line 38} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier", :java true, :file "NumberSequenceClassifier.java", :line 79} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner", :java true, :file "NERClassifierCombiner.java", :line 68} 
{:method "ner", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations", :java true, :file "AnnotatorImplementations.java", :line 99} 
{:method "create", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$6", :java true, :file "AnnotatorFactories.java", :line 319} 
{:method "get", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool", :java true, :file "AnnotatorPool.java", :line 85} 
{:method "construct", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 289} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 126} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 122} 
{:method "start", :class "com.garlicapp.nlp.Initialize", :java true, :file "Initialize.java", :line 35} 
{:method "invoke0", :class "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line nil} 
{:method "invoke", :class "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line 62} 
{:method "invoke", :class "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line 43} 
{:method "invoke", :class "java.lang.reflect.Method", :java true, :file "Method.java", :line 497} 
{:method "invokeMatchingMethod", :class "clojure.lang.Reflector", :java true, :file "Reflector.java", :line 93} 
{:method "invokeNoArgInstanceMember", :class "clojure.lang.Reflector", :java true, :file "Reflector.java", :line 313} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.query", :clojure true, :file "query.clj", :line 19} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start-query", :ns "dandelions.start", :clojure true, :file "start.clj", :line 37} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.start", :clojure true, :file "start.clj", :line 59} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.core", :clojure true, :file "core.clj", :line 10} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "-main", :ns "dandelions.core", :clojure true, :file "core.clj", :line 24} 
{:method "invoke", :class "clojure.lang.RestFn", :java true, :file "RestFn.java", :line 397} 
{:method "applyToHelper", :class "clojure.lang.AFn", :java true, :file "AFn.java", :line 152} 
{:method "applyTo", :class "clojure.lang.RestFn", :java true, :file "RestFn.java", :line 132} 
{:method "main", :class "dandelions.core", :java true, :file nil, :line nil}), :trimmed-elems (
{:method "newInstance0", :class "sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line nil} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line 62} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java", :line 45} 
{:method "newInstance", :class "java.lang.reflect.Constructor", :java true, :file "Constructor.java", :line 422} 
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassFactory", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 229})}, :class edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassCreationException, :message "MetaClass couldn't create public edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties) with args [sutime, 
{ner.model=dependencies/english.all.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz, annotators=tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner}]", :trace-elems (
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassFactory", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 233} 
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 378} 
{:method "loadByReflection", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading", :java true, :file "ReflectionLoading.java", :line 38} 
{:method "create", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java", :line 57} 
{:method "createExtractor", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java", :line 38} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier", :java true, :file "NumberSequenceClassifier.java", :line 79} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner", :java true, :file "NERClassifierCombiner.java", :line 68} 
{:method "ner", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations", :java true, :file "AnnotatorImplementations.java", :line 99} 
{:method "create", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$6", :java true, :file "AnnotatorFactories.java", :line 319} 
{:method "get", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool", :java true, :file "AnnotatorPool.java", :line 85} 
{:method "construct", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 289} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 126} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 122} 
{:method "start", :class "com.garlicapp.nlp.Initialize", :java true, :file "Initialize.java", :line 35} 
{:method "invoke0", :class "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line nil} 
{:method "invoke", :class "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line 62} 
{:method "invoke", :class "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line 43} 
{:method "invoke", :class "java.lang.reflect.Method", :java true, :file "Method.java", :line 497} 
{:method "invokeMatchingMethod", :class "clojure.lang.Reflector", :java true, :file "Reflector.java", :line 93} 
{:method "invokeNoArgInstanceMember", :class "clojure.lang.Reflector", :java true, :file "Reflector.java", :line 313} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.query", :clojure true, :file "query.clj", :line 19} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start-query", :ns "dandelions.start", :clojure true, :file "start.clj", :line 37} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.start", :clojure true, :file "start.clj", :line 59} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.core", :clojure true, :file "core.clj", :line 10} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "-main", :ns "dandelions.core", :clojure true, :file "core.clj", :line 24} 
{:method "invoke", :class "clojure.lang.RestFn", :java true, :file "RestFn.java", :line 397} 
{:method "applyToHelper", :class "clojure.lang.AFn", :java true, :file "AFn.java", :line 152} 
{:method "applyTo", :class "clojure.lang.RestFn", :java true, :file "RestFn.java", :line 132} 
{:method "main", :class "dandelions.core", :java true, :file nil, :line nil}), :trimmed-elems (
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassFactory", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 233} 
{:method "createInstance", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass", :java true, :file "MetaClass.java", :line 378} 
{:method "loadByReflection", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading", :java true, :file "ReflectionLoading.java", :line 38})}, :class edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading$ReflectionLoadingException, :message "Error creating edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl", :trace-elems (
{:method "loadByReflection", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading", :java true, :file "ReflectionLoading.java", :line 40} 
{:method "create", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java", :line 57} 
{:method "createExtractor", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory", :java true, :file "TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java", :line 38} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier", :java true, :file "NumberSequenceClassifier.java", :line 79} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner", :java true, :file "NERClassifierCombiner.java", :line 68} 
{:method "ner", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations", :java true, :file "AnnotatorImplementations.java", :line 99} 
{:method "create", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$6", :java true, :file "AnnotatorFactories.java", :line 319} 
{:method "get", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool", :java true, :file "AnnotatorPool.java", :line 85} 
{:method "construct", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 289} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 126} 
{:method "<init>", :class "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", :java true, :file "StanfordCoreNLP.java", :line 122} 
{:method "start", :class "com.garlicapp.nlp.Initialize", :java true, :file "Initialize.java", :line 35} 
{:method "invoke0", :class "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line nil} 
{:method "invoke", :class "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line 62} 
{:method "invoke", :class "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl", :java true, :file "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java", :line 43} 
{:method "invoke", :class "java.lang.reflect.Method", :java true, :file "Method.java", :line 497} 
{:method "invokeMatchingMethod", :class "clojure.lang.Reflector", :java true, :file "Reflector.java", :line 93} 
{:method "invokeNoArgInstanceMember", :class "clojure.lang.Reflector", :java true, :file "Reflector.java", :line 313} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.query", :clojure true, :file "query.clj", :line 19} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start-query", :ns "dandelions.start", :clojure true, :file "start.clj", :line 37} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.start", :clojure true, :file "start.clj", :line 59} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "start", :ns "dandelions.core", :clojure true, :file "core.clj", :line 10} 
{:anon-fn false, :fn "-main", :ns "dandelions.core", :clojure true, :file "core.clj", :line 24} 
{:method "invoke", :class "clojure.lang.RestFn", :java true, :file "RestFn.java", :line 397} 
{:method "applyToHelper", :class "clojure.lang.AFn", :java true, :file "AFn.java", :line 152} 
{:method "applyTo", :class "clojure.lang.RestFn", :java true, :file "RestFn.java", :line 132} 
{:method "main", :class "dandelions.core", :java true, :file nil, :line nil})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have the models jar in your classpath, so that URL error occurs because it is missing a vital resource.

You will need this file: stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar

It's available with the full distribution of Stanford CoreNLP available here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

If you're still having issues please let me know and I can help step you through it!

Comment: The Java programmer has everything working on his own personal computer. He then used "scp" to transfer everything from his working directory to our development server. Many files are found and are loaded, so I think a lot must be in the classpath. But some file does fail. That is the big confusion. I could put stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar anywhere on the server. I've also done "unzip" and put all the contents on the server. None of this fixes the error.